# React js: Provide base href to npm run build command

Tags: reactjs, react-18

I am building a new react app and I want to provide a base href to my build command similar to angular. I tried this npm run build --base-href='/builPath/' but it didn't work.

Is there an easy way to provide base href in the build command

Comment: what are you trying to achieve, I'm just curious.

Comment: @riazosama If I provide base-href, the bundles will automatically have /buildpath/ to it and it helps with  my nginx path

Comment: have you tried by modifying the build script like `"scripts": {
  "build": "BASE_HREF=/buildPath/ react-scripts build",
},`

Comment: It says 'BASE_HREF' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: are you using windows because windows doesn't handle environment variables in the same way as Unix-based systems. To make this work for all OS, I'd recommend installing `cross-env` package via `npm install --save-dev cross-env
` and then modify the build command to `"build": "cross-env BASE_HREF=/buildPath/ react-scripts build",`